# In MYSQL, what does it mean when there are duplicate indices where everything but key_name is the same?

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-administration, unique-index

```
describe etc_category_metadata;

+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id             | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time_updated        | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_type       | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status_keywords     | mediumblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page_keywords       | mediumblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| profession_keywords | mediumblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| adgroup_ids         | mediumblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| prod                | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| version             | int(11)       | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| status              | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| dep_category_ids    | mediumblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| custom_param        | mediumblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| queue_priority      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| auto_requeue_num    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| cloned_version      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| custom_query        | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description         | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| error_message       | mediumblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time_last_completed | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
21 rows in set (0.40 sec)

show index from etc_category_metadata;
+-----------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                 | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| etc_category_metadata |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id            | A         |       12613 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| etc_category_metadata |          0 | category_type   |            1 | category_type | A         |       12613 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| etc_category_metadata |          0 | category_type   |            2 | version       | A         |       12613 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| etc_category_metadata |          0 | category_type_2 |            1 | category_type | A         |       12613 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| etc_category_metadata |          0 | category_type_2 |            2 | version       | A         |       12613 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| etc_category_metadata |          0 | category_type_3 |            1 | category_type | A         |       12613 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| etc_category_metadata |          0 | category_type_3 |            2 | version       | A         |       12613 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
7 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

Trying to figure out whether it's safe to delete the keys `category_type_2` and `category_type_3`. It seems like they are the exact same indices as `category_type`. This is a legacy table that I have no idea who created a long time ago. Are there any valid reasons someone would end up creating these three keys that seem duplicates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having two *identical* indexes is a waste of disk space and slows down `INSERTs` (a little).  There is no benefit.

You can't really see if they are duplicates from `DESCRIBE TABLE`.  Instead, do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Watch for `UNIQUE`/not, prefixed/not, regular/`FULLTEXT`, created manually / created by `FOREIGN KEY`, etc.

Once you decide that they are identical (except for name), do drop one.  There are other cases where indexes may as well be dropped.  Suppose you had these 3 indexes:

```
INDEX(a,b)  -- keep this
INDEX(a)    -- unnecessary
INDEX(b)    -- keep
```

Or this pair:

```
UNIQUE(a)   -- keep; same as INDEX(a), plus a uniqueness check
INDEX(a)    -- drop
```

More subtle, consider this pair:

```
INDEX(a,b)  -- keep; provides composite index
UNIQUE(a)   -- keep; provides uniqueness check
```

(There are more combinations.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes,you have duplicate indexes on the same column so mysql just add a number if you havent given the indexes a name.IMO,mysql shoudnt even allow duplicate indexes.It is safe to delete them

```
DROP INDEX category_type_2  ON etc_category_metadata
```

and do the same for the others

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason to have multiple indexes on the same columns with the same order. Issues such a create index statement on a current MySQL database will still succeed (for backwards compatibility reasons), but will issue a warning:

> Duplicate index 'index_name' defined on the table 'db.table_name'. This is deprecated and will be disallowed in a future release.

If you have such pre-existing duplicate indexes there's no reason not to remove them.